# Share Point DMS instead of file system

Tags: sharepoint-server, asp.net

We have an application that is developed using ASP.NET through Visual Studio. In that application we have a file upload control. By using the file upload control, we upload files and save them onto the file system.

Now the client wants to save the files in a document management system (e.g. SharePoint) instead of on the file system. Until now we don't have any SharePoint setup, but we are currently installing SharePoint.

My question is; After installing SharePoint, how can I move the ASP.NET application to SharePoint and how can I store the documents in SharePoint instead of on the file system?

Answer (score 0):

As a whole you can not convert or move Asp.Net application in to SharePoint, still if you need to move some modules you have to create web parts and then you can integrate these modules in SharePoint site as features which you can activate and deactivate as desired on page wise and site wise.
SharePoint known for its document collaboration and management ability, it has drag & drop feature to upload files in the SharePoint library. So, you not need to worry just for upload feature in SharePoint. In case you want to create custom feature to upload file you can use your existing ASP.Net code with some code updates as per new SharePoint environment.